# If a particular button, on a SharePoint list is selected, can I have a email sent to someone?

Tags: sharepoint-designer

If a particular button, on a SharePoint list is selected, can I have a email sent to someone?

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably need to wire an [event handler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms453149.aspx) into the list, which is going to require [visual studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/default.aspx). I don't know think you can do it from [designer](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointdesigner/default.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You will need to create a workflow (in SharePoint Designer) to generate an email everytime that button/box is checked. In that email you can also specify the details you want to send over, linked to that item. (realy easy, does not require too much knowledge in SP Designer to do it).